# Highlight a new feature added to angularjs single page application for first time login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Our application is Angularjs single page application, we developed a new feature and we are going live on new feature(service customer can use), so we want to notify the logged in user to that this feature is added and he can use it.

We want a small animation symbol(info symbol) with a tooltip kind of thing displayed when user log ins. We want to show this only a few times(mostly 2 or 3 times he logs in after releasing this feature)

Please suggest a way to achieve this. Ours is angularjs application.

In the stackoverflow documentation tab we can see blue animated bubbles for help as in attached screen, we need similar to that.
[Animated bubble for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkXF7.png)

Please suggest open source stack. Thank You.

Comment: Asking for a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

based on what i understand.

I think this is easy and common, you need a database to store the login attempts(you need an let your backend team to expose an api where you can call to insert new login record to the database) and another api to check the login records for the user.. i guess that it is all about.

for short: (i assume you know backend/frontend things and the Rest API)

1. API for inserting record to database for every successful login
2. API for getting login records

Comment: Backend implementation is straight forward i.e. getting number of logins. We want exactly what opensource library we can use for that help animation popup.